# What does the power saving mode in Miitomo exactly do?

Tags: miitomo

I'm wondering what the power saving mode in Miitomo actually does besides saving battery power. **I'm looking for a detailed list.** If it differs by operating system, please tell the differences between the modes on the operating systems too.

So, what does the power saving mode in Miitomo actually do? (If it for example changes brightness, say that in your answer)

Answer (score 5):

It does not do much more than what you just said : saving battery power by reducing the power consumption of the application. As a counterpart, it will reduce Miitomo's performance, more or less drastically depending on your phone's capacities.

After contacting Nintendo on the matter, here is what they told me about it :

> The power saving mode uses less resources (memory, battery...). It may happen after you activate this option that the application slow down more than if the option was not activated. This option does not affect the notifications you receive.

Comment: But what does it exactly do? I havent noticed a difference between on and off.

Comment: On my phone, at least, it seemed to scale back the framerate of the 3D-rendered stuff.

Comment: Well, I directly contacted Nintendo, because I do not see how else we could have such a specific information.